# Let $F$ be a field and $S$ be subring of $M_n(F)$ generated by all symmetric matrices. Prove that $S=M_n(F)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $S$ be subring of $M_n(F)$ generated by all symmetric matrices. Prove that $S=M_n(F)$

I'm getting no idea how to do it, please help someone

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the 2 by 2 example and its transpose,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & \lambda - 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \lambda \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Yes you are correct ! thanks !